# How to check if a PHP POST array has any value set?

Tags: php

I need to check if any item in an array, that is part of a `$_POST` array, has a value. The values in the empty array are set, so the above example will not produce the desired results.  (This array is a subset of the full `$_POST` array).

```
( 
[columns] => 
[coached_textbox] => 1
[item] => Array
    (
        [first] => Array
            (
                [coach_menu_value] => one
                [coach_menu_name] => Menu One
            )
        [second] => Array
            (
                [coach_menu_value] => 
                [coach_menu_name] => 
            ) 
    (
```

Is there a simple way to test if either array item has a value? I could test each item in the array for value, but that seems inelegant.

This example provided in earlier post gives a fine example on how to test a code initialized `array()` for values.

```
if ($signup_errors) {
  // there was an error
} else {
 // there wasn't
}
```

However, it doesn't work on an array set within a `$_POST` array.

Comment: Earlier post? Why create another post?

Comment: Where is the earlier post? I would like to see the example. Thanks

Comment: I'm confused, what is your question? How to see if an array key has a non-empty string value?

Comment: To check if any item in a $_POST sub array has value. I could loop the sub array and test each for value but I was trying to find a simpler solution, along the lines of the example above. Maybe iterating through the sub array is the only choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a recursive function like below to traverse the array. The function will return `true` if the array contains **at least one non-null value or non-empty string**.

```
function traverseArray($arr){
    $flag = false;
    foreach($arr as $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            $flag = traverseArray($value);
            if($flag) return true;
        }else{
            if(isset($value) && $value != '') return true;
        }
    }
    return $flag;
}
```

And this is how you should call this function, 
*(Suppose `$array` is your original array)*

```
$isNonEmptyArray = traverseArray($array);
if($isNonEmptyArray){
    // At least one element in the array is either 
    // non-null value or non-empty string
}else{
    // Array is completely empty
}
```

Here's a live demo: [**https://eval.in/847211**](https://eval.in/847211)

Comment: This is a cool solution! DIdn't know you could call a function within itself. Thanks.

Comment: @Hispanic100 You're welcome! [Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) is one of the important concepts in any programming language, it comes quite handy in certain situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the empty values and check for `empty()`:

```
if (empty(array_filter($_POST['item']['second']))) {
  // It is empty
} else {
  // It is NOT empty
}
```

Or even just check for falsey value:

```
if (!array_filter($_POST['item']['second'])) {
  // It is empty
} else {
  // It is NOT empty
}
```